# mongodb php update random date on all entries index

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to update random dates in my collection.
The code below is updating ALL entries with the same random date, I would like the loop to iterate thru all the entries and give a different date for each.
I managed to get it to work using an index.
What is the best way to index a large dataset?

```
$date_1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date_2 = strtotime("2012-07-26 09:00:00");

$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->comedy;
$collection = $db->cartoons;

$cursor = $collection->find();

$query = array('_id'=>array('$exists' => true));

foreach ($cursor as $obj){
    $randomDate = rand($date_1,$date_2);

    $collection->update(
        $query,  
        array('$set' => array("ts"=> new MongoDate($randomDate) )), 
        array('multiple' => true)
    );
}
```

**edit:**

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj){
    $randomDate = rand($date_1,$date_2);
    $id = $obj["_id"];
    $collection->update(
        array('_id'=> $id),   
        array('$set' => array("ts"=> new MongoDate($randomDate) )), 
        array('multiple' => true)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on the best way to index really depends on how you are commonly going to query the data.  You need to add appropriate indexes to improve query performance.

For your specific code example, the problem is that you are iterating the collection but passing through a generic `$query` that will match the entire collection:

```
$query = array('_id'=>array('$exists' => true));
```

**and** you are passing `'multiple' => true` which will update every record in the collection that matches.

So the actual result will be to iterate your collection once for every record in the collection, updating all entries in the collection to the current value of `$randomDate`.

The corrected loop would be similar to:

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    $randomDate = rand($date_1, $date_2);
    $collection->update(
        array('_id'=> $obj->['_id']),   
        array('$set' => array('ts' => new MongoDate($randomDate) )), 
        array('multiple' => false)
    );
}
```